Snowflake copy into is unloading a blank line
I am using "copy into" in snowflake to create a .txt file. But every time it is adding a blank line in the end of the file. I tried all the known options, but this blank line is not removing. Can expert please suggest any solution of it?

I am using below file format -
    CREATE FILE FORMAT "DB"."SCH".FF_PIPE_PUBLISH WITH COMPRESSION = 'NONE' FIELD_DELIMITER = '|' RECORD_DELIMITER = '\r\n' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = 'NONE' TRIM_SPACE = FALSE ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = TRUE ESCAPE = 'NONE' EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = FALSE ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = 'NONE' DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' NULL_IF = ();

I am using below copy into -
    COPY INTO @DB.SCH.EXT_FILE_STAGE/new/2024-10-08/text_20241009.txt FROM (SELECT * FROM DB.SCH.FILE_VW) file_format = (format_name = DB.SCH.FF_PIPE_PUBLISH) OVERWRITE = TRUE, SINGLE = TRUE MAX_FILE_SIZE=4900000000 HEADER=FALSE


Have you tried \n instead of \r\n for the record delimiter?

Yes. tried \n too and got same error.

Instead of trying to copy into, can you just run the select * from view with the file format in the picture and see if you are able to see the results set or not? This will help us rule out whether it is the copy into or file format that is causing the unexpected behavior.

I am not sure how to select data from the database view with the file format. I tried to find the way in snowflake documentation but everywhere could not get anything. Can you give me the syntax.  I tried "select * from DB.SCH.FILE_VW (file_format => 'DB.SCH.FF_PIPE_PUBLISH') t"
